# ng-model with multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I'm currently trying to store some data using AngularJS. I have a table with different sections, as well as rows and columns.

Each field has a dropdown-list, containing just the letters "O","T" or "E". What I want is to store these values in an array: [section][row][column] - e.g. [0][0][0] = "E".

This is how I tried to store the values:

```
<select id="{{$parent.$parent.$index}}_{{$parent.$index}}_{{$index}}"
    ng-change="changePollValue()"
    ng-model="selectedValues[$parent.$parent.$index][$parent.$index][$index]" ...>
```

Unfortunately, AngularJS is creating nested objects inside of a one-dimensional array. Like this:

```
   "selectedValues" : [ {
              "0" : {
                "0" : "E",
                "1" : "T",
                "2" : "O",
                "3" : "E",
                "4" : "T"
              },
              "1" : {
                "0" : "O",
                "1" : "E",
                "2" : "T",
                "3" : "O",
                "4" : "E"
...
```

"selectedValues" is initialized like `$scope.selectedValues = [];`

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you really want is a matrix, and that is not how you produce a matrix in javascript. This is how a three-dimensional matrix is produced:

```
$scope.matrix = [[[]]];
```

Like this you have a parent array that has a child that is another array (this makes a simple matrix) and then, this child has yet another child array (a grandchild to the parent array), which then becomes a three dimensional array. Take a look at a three dimensional array definition with some children and grandchildren:

```
$scope.matrix = [
  [
    [
      { selectedOption: '0-0-0' },
      { selectedOption: '0-0-1' },
      { selectedOption: '0-0-2' }
    ], [
      { selectedOption: '0-1-0' },
      { selectedOption: '0-1-1' },
      { selectedOption: '0-1-2' }
    ]
  ], [
    [
      { selectedOption: '1-0-0' },
      { selectedOption: '1-0-1' },
      { selectedOption: '1-0-2' }
    ], [
      { selectedOption: '1-1-0' },
      { selectedOption: '1-1-1' },
      { selectedOption: '1-1-2' }
    ]
  ]
];
```

In this case the first digit relates to the parent index, the second digit (after the hyphen) relates to the child index and the third index (after the last hyphen) relates to the grandchild index. So 1-1-1 points to the second parent (0 base index), and to the second child and to the second grandchild.

I have made an example on [codepen to illustrate how to handle this](http://codepen.io/bruno_krebs/pen/GNEarM).

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of the [[[]]]-syntax to create a matrix. I tried the Java-syntax, but that didn't work.

Comment: No problem @DCH. If this really helped you and is the right answer, you can mark it as so. Have fun.